# How would you solve this problem using recursion and without other looping methods?

Tags: javascript, recursion

The function below returns multiples of 2 between num1 / num2.
So in case where num 1 = 8, num 2 = 12, it will return 3 as such multiples equal to 8, 10, 12.
How would you duplicate this function using recursion only?

```
function makeMultiplesOfDigit(num1, num2) {
  let count = 0;
  let start = num1;
  let end = num2;

  if (num1 > num2) {
    start = num2;
    end = num1;
  }

  if (start === 0) {
    start = 1;
  }

  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: Why the  `if (start === 0)`? According to the book, 0 is an even number, and it should thus be counted as one. What's more, if `num1` is negative and `num2` is positive, then 0 *will* be counted as one of the even numbers. So that just does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This was a problem originally intended for beginner coders who only started learning coding. I guess they (bootcamp) tried to make it easier by giving exception to 0. Now about 3 weeks passed from the first time I saw the problem, I am trying to apply what I learned from recursion so I can practice. By the way, I really appreciate your clear explanation. Thank you much.

Comment: Note that the function name in the question does not at all match what it is supposed to do.  Perhaps something like `countEvens`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is not really the right method to this problem, as there is a closed formula for this, but here you go:

```js
function makeMultiplesOfDigit(num1, num2) {
  if (num1 > num2) return makeMultiplesOfDigit(num2, num1);
  let isEven = 1 - num1 % 2;
  if (num1 == num2) return isEven; // base case
  return isEven + makeMultiplesOfDigit(num1 + 1, num2);
}

// demo
console.log(makeMultiplesOfDigit(8, 12));
```

Note: your code does not count 0 as an even number when `num1` is 0, which is strange: surely 0 is an even number. And if the function were called with (-1, 1), then it would still count 0 as even, so it is not consistent either.

As an additional information, here is the closed formula version:

```js
function makeMultiplesOfDigit(num1, num2) {
  return ((Math.abs(num1 - num2) + 1) >> 1) + (num1 % 2 === 0 && num2 % 2 === 0);
}

// demo
console.log(makeMultiplesOfDigit(8, 12));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeMultiplesOfDigit(num1,num2,count=0){
        if (num1 % 2 === 0 ){
            count++
         }
        if(num1>=num2){
            return count
         }
        else{
           count = makeMultiplesOfDigit(num1+1,num2,count)
           return count
         }
      }
  

    makeMultiplesOfDigit(8, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw a similar response, anyway, here you go.

```js
function getMultiplesInRange(num1, num2, num3 = 0) {
  if (num1 > num2) return num3
  const val = num1 % 2 === 0 ? 1 : 0
  return getMultiplesInRange(num1 + 1, num2, val + num3)
}

console.log(getMultiplesInRange(8, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with a situation where the first number is smaller than the second number:

```js
// Generic utils
const isEven = (n) => n % 2 === 0 
const eq = (a, b) => a === b
const inc = (n) => n + 1
const add = (a, b) => a + b

// Constants
const incCount = 1
const leaveCount = 0

// Implementation
const shouldIncCount = (n) => isEven(n) ? incCount : leaveCount
const makeMultiplesOfDigit = (a, b) => eq(a, b) ? shouldIncCount(a) : add(shouldIncCount(a), makeMultiplesOfDigit(inc(a), b));
```